# Julia: How to row filtering by bitarray for `DataFrames.DataFrameColumns`?

Tags: julia

In the past I can do

```
using DataFrames
a = DataFrames.DataFrame(a=1:3)

a[[true, false, true], :]
```

but

```
Tables.columns(a)[[true, false, true], :])
```

Doesn't work anymore since `Tables.columns` returns a `DataFrames.DataFrameColumns`.

I want to write code that's workable for all Tables.jl compatible tables, so I don't want to check for special types.

Comment: in general Tables.jl compliant table does not have to support `Bool` indexing. A standard general approach (but not strictly what you want) would be to use `TableOperations.filter` function.

Comment: I want to reduce memory usage as much as possible. Is it possible to do a view?

Comment: I think you would need to write your own wrapper. Note that in general Tables.jl compliant table does not even have to be stored in memory at all - it might be e.g. lazily dynamically loaded.

Comment: Why don't use `Tables.columns` after row indexing. I.e. `Tables.columns(a[[true, false, true], :])`?